# Sturm-Liouville system boundary conditions

Tags: fourier-series

I have a question about the various boundary conditions of a Sturm-Liouville system. I've been told that there are five different possible conditions for the system. However, can't seem to find them. Also, is there a specific condition that the Fourier series satisfies? If so, how can I obtain such a collection of the boundary conditions?